# Using Sling Launchpad for production

Tags: osgi, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I was trying to understand deployment scenarios for Sling/JCR when I started wondering if I could simply use the [Sling Launchpad](http://sling.apache.org/site/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html) and simply start the server using the jar. My project needs simplicity more than performance, but is there something seriously wrong with this approach? Alternatively, is there a good place where Sling/JCR deployment is discussed in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we have a detailed description on how to deploy Sling applications, the best might be to ask on the users mailing list ( http://sling.apache.org/site/project-information.html#ProjectInformation-lists ) so that others can share their experiences.

As for starting with the launchpad I don't see a problem with that, that's pretty much how we are using Sling in Adobe CQ5. We have our own customized launcher that adds a few features, mostly related to upgrades management, but the basics are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Although the few details of your project, I can say that Sling-Launchpad is a very useful tool to start an OSGi environment with selectable bundles. You just make a list of bundles to be included in the environment. It is very actively used in [Apache Stanbol](http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/) project. For the details you can investigate the various launchers of Stanbol e.g [full](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/stanbol/trunk/launchers/full/), [full-war](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/stanbol/trunk/launchers/full-war/), [etc](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/stanbol/trunk/launchers/). Those launchers produce a single jar file including the necessary files to start the server.

Answer (score 1):

Cryo-answer, maybe better late than never.
As long as you're not after a clustered config, the sling trunk build now has a debian contrib module that packages the launchpad jar in a debian package. It's a simplistic packaging mechanism that doesn't fully exploit all possible use cases, but it does setup logging and provide an etc/defaults for for config setup.